# <!-- language: javascript --> highlighting broken?

Tags: support, bug, tags, edits, syntax-highlighting

**tl;dr** from [T.J. Crowder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376704/language-javascript-highlighting-broken/376786#comment647962_376704):

1. A question without a language tag using Java or JavaScript syntax doesn't get syntax highlighted.
2. Adding `<!-- language: java -->` to it gives it Java syntax highlighting.
3. Adding `<!-- language: javascript -->` to it does not give it JavaScript syntax highlighting; instead, you have to use `<!-- language: lang-javascript -->` or `<!-- language: lang-js -->`.

Yup, sounds like a bug -- or at least, a feature enabled for Java (`java` as a synonym for `lang-java`) that isn't enabled for JavaScript.

---

Original post:

I frequently edit posts to add JavaScript or Java syntax highlighting.

The way I've done that is by adding something like this to the top of the code in the post:

```
<!-- language: java -->
<!-- language: javascript -->
```

More info here: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/294611)

This appears to work for the Java edits, but does not work for the JavaScript edits.

However, if I use the `lang` syntax:

```
<!-- language: lang-javascript -->
```

Then it works okay.

From my understanding, I shouldn't have to use `lang-javascript`, and just `javascript` should work okay.

Just to test, here's a code block that uses `<!-- language: javascript -->`:

```
function hello(){
  console.log('hello');
}
```

And here's one that uses `<!-- language: lang-javascript -->`:

```javascript
function hello(){
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Notice that the first block is not highlighted. Is this a bug, or am I incorrect in expecting `<!-- language: javascript -->` to work?

**Edit:** Some people have mentioned that the Java highlighting might be automatically triggered. However, if I **don't** add `<!-- language: java -->` to the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) questions, then they are **not** automatically highlighted. If I add `<!-- language: java -->` then they are highlighted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252980/873165) is an example answer where I did **not** add it, and it's not highlighted. The question itself does have the `<!-- language: java -->` part, so it is highlighted.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53226663/873165) is an example of `<!-- language: lang-javascript -->` working.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53316200/873165) is an example of `<!-- language: javascript -->` **not** working.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252980/873165) is an example answer where I did **not** add any language markup, and it's **not** automatically highlighted. I did edit the question to include the language markup, so it **is** highlighted.

Comment: It looks like the `lang-` prefixes are consistently required.  In the language codes section, each of them has that prefix, including the javascript one.

Comment: Just checking: do those posts you add a language to happen to be tagged with something whose default language is already set to something that happens to highlight appropriately anyway?

Comment: @ryanyuyu But shouldn't you also be able to use a tag? Here's an example of `<!-- language: java -->` working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252638/how-should-i-get-a-connected-array-of-circles-like-a-worm-to-move-across-my-ca

Comment: @JonClements I don't think so. I mostly edit [tag:processing] questions to include Java syntax highlighting, and [tag:p5.js] questions to include JavaScript syntax highlighting.

Comment: I think that's luck @KevinWorkman.  The syntax highlight just kinda guesses if you don't have the lang tag.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: yep. From Github: "You don't need to specify the language since PR.prettyPrint() will guess." I didn't check any deeper but I guess () that's what it also does when you enter an unknown language.

Comment: @usr2564301 The weird thing is, if I don't add `<!-- language: java -->` to [tag:processing] questions, then they are **not** automatically highlighted. If I add `<!-- language: java -->` then they **are** highlighted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252980/873165) is an example answer where I did **not** add it, and it's not highlighted. The question itself does have the `<!-- language: java -->` part, so it is highlighted.

Comment: I suspect the test in your question is not working because those tags do not exist in Meta. If I try it in the answer box here, the preview shows `language: lang-hs` works for Haskell, while `language: haskell` doesn't; and yet answers on the main site using `language: haskell` are highlighted correctly ([arbitrary example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41354409/2751851)). It might be useful for us to see an example of a [javascript] question which is mishighlighted in the way you describe.

Comment: @duplode I've included a couple example questions and answers that exhibit this behavior.

Comment: @KevinWorkman In your second example, adding the [javascript] tag makes `language: javascript` work (I checked it through the edit preview), so it seems this form of the language hint only works if the question has a matching tag.

Comment: @duplode Yes, questions with the [tag:javascript] tag are automatically highlighted, without any language markup at all. I'm working with questions that are **not** tagged with [tag:javascript] though.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I get that, and I'm not suggesting you add the tag. There are cases in which you still need a language hint even if the tag is there; namely, when there is also another, more popular language tag in the question. For instance, if a question is tagged [scala] and [haskell], the Haskell code blocks need the hint. My point is that `language: foobar` is only useful in cases like that (for [javascript] in particular, it is never useful, as it is the most popular tag on the site).

Comment: Not sure this is a [meta-tag:bug], but rather a [meta-tag:support] question, instead.

Comment: For what its worth,`<!-- language: lang-js -->` works for me as does `<!-- language: lang-ts -->` for typescript

Comment: I have always used `<!-- language: matlab -->`, never needed to do `lang-matlab` (on posts also tagged with Python, which seems to get priority over MATLAB in syntax highlighting, so much for "PR.prettyPrint() will guess.").

Comment: So the TL;DR is: 1. A question without a language tag using Java or JavaScript syntax doesn't get syntax highlighted. 2. Adding `<!-- language: java -->` to it gives it Java syntax highlighting. 3. Adding `<!-- language: javascript -->` to it does **not** give it JavaScript syntax highlighting; instead, you have to use `<!-- language: lang-javascript -->` or `<!-- language: lang-js -->`. Yup, sounds like a bug -- or at least, a feature enabled for Java (`java` as a synonym for `lang-java`) that isn't enabled for JavaScript.

Comment: Did nobody else notice that the first two hyphens in the title got changed into an m-dash, but the second two didn't? I have problems looking past that. Yeah, I know it's me, but still. Instead of concentrating on the question, I'm now puzzling on what logic could be used to produce such a result.

Comment: @MrLister The logic seems to be, any `--` followed by a space get replaced by a dash. Does it work in comments-- no.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the summary. I added that to the top of my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `lang-...`, it will use that language. If you use the name of a tag, it will use the default code language set for that type. If you look at the tag wiki for a tag, it will tell you the code language set for that tag. For Java it's `lang-java`, for JavaScript, it's `default`. So `<!-- language: javascript -->` will enable the default highlighting (meaning it will try to detect the language), not JavaScript highlighting, because that's the setting for the tag.

I assume it's done this way because questions tagged JavaScript contain code in other languages (such as HTML) more often than Java questions, so highlighting all code as JavaScript code in questions tagged JavaScript would lead to wrong highlighting more often.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you tag a question [tag:javascript], it gets syntax-highlighted. If you put `<!-- language: javascript -->` in it (without [tag:javascript]), it doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Tagging with `javascript` used to set the default “best effort” highlighter. Using `<!— language: [tagname] —>` on the other hand will never fall back to the default highlighter, so you end up with nothing. I’ve now set the tag to use `lang-js`.

Answer (score 1):

[Martijn Pieters ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) has fixed this now. From [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376704/language-javascript-highlighting-broken#comment736720_376786):

> Tagging with `javascript` used to set the default “best effort” highlighter. Using `<!-- language: [tagname] -->` on the other hand will never fall back to the default highlighter, so you end up with nothing. I’ve now set the tag to use `lang-js`.

...which means that a question with this markdown (and without the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag) gets syntax-highlighted correctly now:

```
Testing 1 2 3

<!-- language: javascript -->

    console.log("Testing 1 2 3");
```

Of course, JavaScript questions generally should have [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), but for the cases where there seems to be a good reason not to include it...